# ajax refresh code

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need some ajax code to assign value to a session

for example

$_SESSION['verif_code']

i am generating a random number to assign value to this session

i need some ajax code to refresh this random number function and assign value to this session.

does any one have an idea please share it with me

Thanks

Comment: How is the random value being generated? We need more details.

Comment: You should use a Guid instead of a random number, a random number could have too much hit (two sessions having the same random number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to replace all commented out sections with your own code, but here is a generalized template for AJAX requests.

Inside of your HTML/PHP file, where the AJAX will take affect.

---

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="submit" onclick="generateCaptcha()">
<div id="captcha">Your captcha div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your Javascript code to call the AJAX request.

---

```
var xmlhttp;

function generateCaptcha()   {
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null) {
  alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
  return;
  }
var url="yourfile.php"; // file to send the AJAX request too, see below
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()  {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) { // success.
   // generate your new captcha
 }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
return null;
}
```

Your PHP file inside of the AJAX call, named *yourfile.php* will process the data returned and will do whatever data manipulation is needed back to your `div` element without a page refresh.

Take an overview of [**AJAX Tutorial**](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) before you jump into things.